# Custom HTTP Headers for WebView Requests

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to modify the HTTP request headers of a React Native WebView component on iOS?

I'm aware of the `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` function but this doesn't seem to allow any possibility for modification.

Comment: Did you have any solution yet?

Comment: No solution yet.  Sorry  :(

Answer (score 10):

You can put your request header on attribute `headers` like this:

```
<WebView source={{
  uri: "http://blog.apentle.com/",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic YXBlbnRsZS5jb206YXBlbnRsZQ==",
  }
}}
style={styles.webview} />
```

Comment: This does not apply headers to other requests made by the js code from the loaded page. Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: @AdamLagevik In a clean way? NO. What we had to do is to inject javascript into the web view that was loading other resources and add them by ourselves. There are a couple of stack overflow questions about that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029978/adding-custom-headers-in-javascript-for-all-http-requests

Comment: WebView uses these headers just to fetch the content from URL you provided. It never sets any cookie or header in webview, you'll have to manage that on webpage itself.

Check when the request is coming from mobile WebView and set header on response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is solution that works also for also for subsequent calls in the WebView - you can track the current URL, intercept new page loads, and navigate to them yourself (original credit for this technique to Chirag Shah from Big Binary)

```
const CustomHeaderWebView = (props) => {
  const { uri, onLoadStart, ...restProps } = props;
  const [currentURI, setURI] = useState(props.source.uri);
  const newSource = { ...props.source, uri: currentURI };

  return (
    <WebView
      {...restProps}
      source={newSource}
      onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(request) => {
        // If we're loading the current URI, allow it to load
        if (request.url === currentURI) return true;
        // We're loading a new URL -- change state first
        setURI(request.url);
        return false;
      }}
    />
  );
};

<CustomHeaderWebView
  source={{
    uri: 'http://example.com',
    headers: {
      'my-custom-header-key': 'my-custom-header-value',
    },
  }}
/>;
```

Source: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#working-with-custom-headers-sessions-and-cookies